# Documents for a Website tester?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I'm a Website tester. I don't know how to write some test tools. I'm looking for some documents which teach how to write test tools: automated test, JavaScript test, PHP test, Unit Test....
If there is any example, please show me.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very vague; are you looking for examples of unit/automated/test tools written in these languages?

Here are some automation resources that I think would help you clarify your question a bit.

- [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org) is a toolkit that will allow you to write DOM-rich automated tests and run them within a variety of browsers. There are wrappers for selensese (the language that interacts with the running DOM during tests) in a variety of languages. My organization uses Selenium-RC along with PHPUnit to write Selenium test cases for our web application.
- [Watir](http://www.watir.com) is a ruby-based framework that allows testing similar in nature to selenium. The tests are written in ruby, but the test coverage that they add is over Javascript, rendered PHP; the tests are automated.

Each of these systems provides what I would consider to be *integration* tests. Selenium has been implemented in PHP by PHPUnit, so you have everything available to you in these test cases that you would have in a unit test. The difference is purely semantic. You're testing *functionality* of the site, rather than the ability of a small unit of the code to respond to something specific.

Comment: First, thank you for helping me and sorry about my vague question. I want to learn how to write a test for a website, just a basic test. First, I didn't wanna use tools, but your answer made me think again. If you have any document teaching how to write a test, please introduce it to me. Thanks a lot. P.S.: I'm learning to use above tools :).

Comment: I need help. I recognize that Selenium must be installed on server and clients. I'm using firebug to test and edit. Is there any tools just use for client?

Comment: Typically, one will install either Selenium-RC as a service on the machine on which they intend to test; _or_ they will install a Selenium WebDriver (which will handle all of the details). If you want to use PHP to run your Selenium tests, you'll need to go through the motions of installing PHPUnit, which provides a basic interface with Selenium-RC through it's PHPUnit_Selenium_TestCase class. For more information, check out [PHPUnit and Selenium](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/selenium.html)